# How to display the user id in encryption form within the view section of the JEE web application?

Tags: java, jsp, encryption

I have created my web application in standard MVC format (Controller, beans, DAO, JSP pages). Now within the view section i.e. in the JSP page a user can get the list of other co-users of the application and can visit their profiles by clicking on their names. For this the link should be having the id of the user. But I don't want the id to be displayed within view section as this will be the same id that is stored in the database so I'm concerned about the security issues. So my question is their a way through which I could encrypt this displayed id.

Comment: Why is this a security issue ? Unless your database can be accessed openly and all the tables queried, I do not see a problem.

Comment: @DeepakBala I'm not much familiar with the concepts that how your system can be hacked, but do you think there would be no security issues if I display this id openly?

Comment: Well as long as your take reasonable security precautions there should be no problem. For example if you do not use a `PreparedStatement` your queries could be vulnerable to an SQL injection and the IDs could be misused. But then again the SQL injection can be misused with wildcards anyway. There is no harm in displaying the internal ID. Just ensure that authentication and auhtorization barriers are in place.

Comment: @DeepakBala thanks didnt know PreparedStatement could serve such security purposes (Y)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to expose the user IDs directly in the UI, you can access the user Profile using some other field like "user-name" for example, but you must ensure this particular field is UNIQUE on your database, so your links might end up like this:
EXAMPLE --> "localhost:8080/myApp/userProfile?userName=joe123"